# Game Maker Studio 2 - room physics and object physics

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I want to make a simulation where a ball is thrown with a random force and there is gravity. 
I used 'create' event and 'motion_set' function. It works when room physics is turned off. When I turn it on, the ball just drops, motion_set doesn't seem to have any effect.
I tried with Drag and Drop too. The result was the same.

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Using physics_apply_local_impulse instead worked. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both: the classic system and the physic system work both at the same time, either you enable physics in your room and in which case you have to move your objects using physics functions, but other functions like speed, hspeed, vspeed, motion_set, gravity, friction...etc won't be working, unless you implement them manually. Or you disable physics and use those classic functions I just mentioned

Goodluck!